# How I pass the static variable values from Users.java to UsersFragment.java file using adapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I want to pass the static variables from Users.java to UsersFragment.java but the given below error will occurs...
I am trying to solve this error from last 2 days.

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.login, PID: 9070
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.example.login.Users
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:547)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:329)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:430)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:231)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:203)
        at com.example.login.ui.login.UsersFragment$1.onDataChange(UsersFragment.java:59)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I the upper error, my error is

```
at com.example.login.ui.login.UsersFragment$1.onDataChange(UsersFragment.java:59)
```

& the useful 2 java files are given below

**Users.java**

```
package com.example.login;

public class Users {
    private static String UserName;
    private static String UserPhone;
    private static String UserDesc;
    private static String UserEmail;
    private static String UserID;

    public Users(String userName,String userPhone,String userDesc,String userEmail, String userID) {
       this.UserName = userName;
       this.UserPhone = userPhone;
       this.UserDesc = userDesc;
       this.UserEmail = userEmail;
       this.UserID = userID;
    }

    public Users() {
    }

    public static String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public static void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public static String getUserPhone() {
        return UserPhone;
    }

    public static void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        UserPhone = userPhone;
    }

    public static String getUserDesc() {
        return UserDesc;
    }

    public static void setUserDesc(String userDesc) {
        UserDesc = userDesc;
    }

    public static String getUserEmail() {
        return UserEmail;
    }

    public static void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        UserEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public static String getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public static void setUserID(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }
}
```

**UsersFragment.java**

```
package com.example.login.ui.login;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.login.R;
import com.example.login.UserAdapter;
import com.example.login.Users;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<Users> users;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users,container,false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        users = new ArrayList<>();

        readUsers();

        return view;
    }

    private void readUsers() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                users.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Users user = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                    assert firebaseUser != null;
                    if(!Users.getUserID().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                        users.add(user);
                        Log.d("hhh",String.valueOf(users));
                    }
                }

                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), users);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please Solve my error, I am very embarrassed...

Comment: How can you pass multiple Users when all fields are static? The static fields are shared between instances and all Users will have the same values.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using static variables specially in that class.
Like other people said you have to implement Serializable or even better Parcelable(the serializable interface for android)

Comment: if I don't use static variables then at login activity the username will not set using ```setUserName()``` method

```public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Users.setUserName(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).toString());

                SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sh.edit();
                myEdit.putString("name",Users.getUserName());
            }```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implements your Users object class to Serializable like this:

```
package com.example.login;

public class Users implements Serializable {
private static String UserName;
private static String UserPhone;
private static String UserDesc;
private static String UserEmail;
private static String UserID;

public Users(String userName,String userPhone,String userDesc,String userEmail, String userID) {
   this.UserName = userName;
   this.UserPhone = userPhone;
   this.UserDesc = userDesc;
   this.UserEmail = userEmail;
   this.UserID = userID;
}

public Users() {
}

public static String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public static void setUserName(String userName) {
    UserName = userName;
}

public static String getUserPhone() {
    return UserPhone;
}

public static void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
    UserPhone = userPhone;
}

public static String getUserDesc() {
    return UserDesc;
}

public static void setUserDesc(String userDesc) {
    UserDesc = userDesc;
}

public static String getUserEmail() {
    return UserEmail;
}

public static void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    UserEmail = userEmail;
}

public static String getUserID() {
    return UserID;
}

public static void setUserID(String userID) {
    UserID = userID;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, your class needs to implement the Serializable interface:

```
class User implements Serializable {}
```

It’s also not understandable why you use static, static is used when the variable is one for all objects, but i think you have different users

Comment: What does not work ? Did you implement the interface? Some kind of mistake?

Comment: I implemented serializable as you told me. but same error will occured

Comment: I think the problem is using static

Comment: but if I don't use the static then username will not set using ```Users.setUserName(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).toString());``` code...

Comment: You misunderstand what static is, using static you cannot use information about several users, since you save information about only one. You need to rewrite the code using not static variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209289/discussion-between-pratik-bharad-and-destroyer).